# Upgrade to 20.04 - Blocked by third party software (?)

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates

While upgrading to 20.04, I bumped into the following problem:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This was likely caused by: 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.
```

How to figure out which package to delete, if any?

In `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`
I get a lot of lines that look like:

```
Broken libk3b7:amd64 Breaks on libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 | 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umH > (< 18.08.3~)
  Considering libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 2 as a solution to libk3b7:amd64 4
  Upgrading libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 due to Breaks field in libk3b7:amd64
Investigating (9) libk3b7-extracodecs:amd64 < 17.12.3-0ubuntu3 -> 19.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
```

Is that an indication of a problem?

The output of `sudo apt-update` is clean:

```
Hit:1 http://files.eid.belgium.be/debian bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com bionic InRelease                                                                                                                              
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                       
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                               
Hit:6 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                        
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]      
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:9 http://files2.eid.belgium.be/debian bionic InRelease    
Hit:10 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                       
Fetched 252 kB in 3s (76.6 kB/s)                                         
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Then I disabled all repositories except for the canonical ones.
I no longer get an error about third party software. All I get is the error message: `An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.`

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1302200/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: The `download.sublimetext.com` repo looks suspicious. Try to disable that to start with.

Comment: It seems like this is a relatively common problem. Searching for "upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade" spit out quite a few articles. It has already been logged as a bug.

Comment: @MarcCorluy: Somebody reporting a similar issue as a bug doesn't necessarily mean that it is a bug. Can you please let us know which Ubuntu version you are on currently and, if a desktop, is it standard Ubuntu or one of the flavors. Also, which tool are you using when trying to upgrade?

Comment: This is indeed a common question...usually from users who 1) have added non-Ubuntu repositories that provide conflicting packages, and 2) do not keep track of what they installed. Your log snippet confirms that you seem to have  a classic *version conflict*, which is expected in such circumstances. Definitely not a bug. A wise practice is to A) Keep track of what you install, and B) Be prepared to use your tracking to return your system to as close to stock condition as possible --uninstalling all packages from all non-Ubuntu sources. You can reinstall after the release-upgrade is successful.

Comment: Just disabling the repos does not get rid of the problematic packages. Suggest using `ppa-purge` which will remove packages not in the official repos and replace those which are with official versions.